# Javascript split function for getting name from a whole link?

Tags: javascript

I have several link like this:

```
https://www.globenewswire.com/news-release/2022/02/05/2379566/673/en/ROSEN-GLOBAL-INVESTOR-COUNSEL-Encourages-Reata-Pharmaceuticals-Inc-Investors-With-Losses-Over-100K-to-Secure-Counsel-Before-Important-February-18-Deadline-in-Securities-Class-Actio.html
```

Or, it can be:

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/m/597b7dc4-eecf-3b45-83ac-fa87ba542bbf/bitcoin-is-back-over-%2441%2C000.html

https://www.dailyfx.com/forex/fundamental/forecast/weekly/title/2022/02/06/Mexican-Peso-Outlook-US-Inflation-Data-Banxico-Decision-will-Be-Key-for-USDMXN.html
```

Anything. But I need the domain name. How can I get that.

Here from this two links, I need:

- Finace Yahoo
- Globe News Wire
- Daily Fx

How can I find that using JavaScript.

Comment: You can certainly obtain the domain name, but splitting that domain name (dailyfx.com) into "Daily FX" can't be obtained directly, as JavaScript has no innate concept of language, without extra coding in your part. Now, what have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Now, Actually I am not getting any idea, How can I start?

Comment: That's why I am stacking on starting point. Can you help me with this, by giving an example or idea

Answer (score 1):

> Notice that solution won't help in case do you have multiple subdomains.

```
function getHostname(url) {
   let __url = new URL(url);
   __url = __url.origin.split("//")[1]
   
  if (__url.includes("www.")) {
    __url = __url.replace("www.", "");
  }
  
  return __url.split(".")[0]

}
console.log(getHostname(YOUR_URL_HERE))
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```js
// Object mapping a known domain name to that domain's (already-known) name:
const linkMap = {
  'www.globenewswire.com': 'Globe News Wire',
  'finance.yahoo.com': 'Yahoo Finance',
  'www.dailyfx.com': 'Daily FX'
};

// selecting the first <button> element, and binding the anonymous
// function as the event-handler for the 'click' event:
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // selecing all <a> elements that are found within <li> elements,
  // iterating over them with nodeList.prototype.forEach():
  document.querySelectorAll('li a').forEach(
    // setting the text-content of the <a> element to be equal to
    // the value of the hostname as retrieved from the <a> element:
    (anchor) => anchor.textContent = linkMap[anchor.hostname]
  );
});
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: normal 1rem / 1.5 sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  justify-content: end;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: clamp(15em, 600px, 80vw);
}

li:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><button>Identify Links</button></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.globenewswire.com/news-release/2022/02/05/2379566/673/en/ROSEN-GLOBAL-INVESTOR-COUNSEL-Encourages-Reata-Pharmaceuticals-Inc-Investors-With-Losses-Over-100K-to-Secure-Counsel-Before-Important-February-18-Deadline-in-Securities-Class-Actio.html">Link 1</a></li>

  <li><a href="https://finance.yahoo.com/m/597b7dc4-eecf-3b45-83ac-fa87ba542bbf/bitcoin-is-back-over-%2441%2C000.html">Link 2</a></li>

  <li><a href="https://www.dailyfx.com/forex/fundamental/forecast/weekly/title/2022/02/06/Mexican-Peso-Outlook-US-Inflation-Data-Banxico-Decision-will-Be-Key-for-USDMXN.html">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

A slightly revised approach, which takes into account that you may not have a map of domains to names:

```js
const linkMap = {
  'www.globenewswire.com': 'Globe News Wire',
  'finance.yahoo.com': 'Yahoo Finance',
  'www.dailyfx.com': 'Daily FX'
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('li a').forEach(
    (anchor) => {
      //  here we cache the result from the linkMap:
      let siteName = linkMap[anchor.hostname];
      // here using a conditional operator (ternary) to test if there is a falsy result
      // from the Object, if there is we return the hostname after replacing the 'www' (if it exists)
      // and then take the substring from the first (0) character to the last '.' character; this
      // is a simple approach because it assumes the last '.' precedes the TLD but does not
      // account for sites such as '.co.uk' as an example.
      anchor.textContent = !siteName ? anchor.hostname.replace('www.', '').substring(0, anchor.hostname.lastIndexOf(".")) : siteName
    });
});
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: normal 1rem / 1.5 sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  justify-content: end;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: clamp(15em, 600px, 80vw);
}

li:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><button>Identify Links</button></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.globenewswire.com/news-release/2022/02/05/2379566/673/en/ROSEN-GLOBAL-INVESTOR-COUNSEL-Encourages-Reata-Pharmaceuticals-Inc-Investors-With-Losses-Over-100K-to-Secure-Counsel-Before-Important-February-18-Deadline-in-Securities-Class-Actio.html">Link 1</a></li>

  <li><a href="https://finance.yahoo.com/m/597b7dc4-eecf-3b45-83ac-fa87ba542bbf/bitcoin-is-back-over-%2441%2C000.html">Link 2</a></li>

  <li><a href="https://www.dailyfx.com/forex/fundamental/forecast/weekly/title/2022/02/06/Mexican-Peso-Outlook-US-Inflation-Data-Banxico-Decision-will-Be-Key-for-USDMXN.html">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using regex

```
const extractNameWithoutTLD = (url) => {
  const regex = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)/g;
  const match = regex.exec(url);
  return match[1].replace(/\.[^.]+$/, '');
}
console.log(
  extractNameWithoutTLD(
    'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/597b7dc4-eecf-3b45-83ac-fa87ba542bbf/bitcoin-is-back-over-%2441%2C000.html'
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript solution**

```
const domain = new URL(url).hostname.replace('www.', '');
```

```js
const urls = [
  'https://www.dailyfx.com/forex/fundamental/forecast/weekly/title/2022/02/06/Mexican-Peso-Outlook-US-Inflation-Data-Banxico-Decision-will-Be-Key-for-USDMXN.htmll',
  'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/597b7dc4-eecf-3b45-83ac-fa87ba542bbf/bitcoin-is-back-over-%2441%2C000.html',
  'https://www.globenewswire.com/news-release/2022/02/05/2379566/673/en/ROSEN-GLOBAL-INVESTOR-COUNSEL-Encourages-Reata-Pharmaceuticals-Inc-Investors-With-Losses-Over-100K-to-Secure-Counsel-Before-Important-February-18-Deadline-in-Securities-Class-Actio.html',
];

urls.map((url) => {
  const domain = new URL(url).hostname.replace('www.', '');
  console.log(domain)
});
```